# CiviCase - Edit Actions with permission: "CiviCase: access my cases and activities"

Tags: civicase, permissions

Im Configurating CiviCase and I have seen that if a contact has the "CiviCase: access my cases and activities" permission, he cannot use the actions of the assigned roles.
I understand that this permission has certain limitations, but I think this should be available, maybe I am wrong, but I think it would be interesting to be able to eliminate the assigned roles or change the person from the role since the case is created by the user who edits it.

Answer (score 2):

It was done deliberately in 2010 and it's been that way ever since. While it's not stated in the JIRA link below, if I had to guess the reason it's because it might allow you to give your buddy access to a case they shouldn't see.

See

- https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-5666
- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-svn/commit/d3cc0a1d87d86bbdc5eeda2a8975e382fcf66576#diff-33fb19b4d7d2903e556b3c4a2ed1ffd5L129-L130